# Upgrade of Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, subscription

We recently submitted a Windows Phone app for the Imagine Cup Round 2 Windows Phone competition. We were using Windows Azure services for our Windows Phone App. Unfortunately, our Azure subscription has reached its limit and has been disabled. The Imagine Cup team gave us a free 180 day trial period for Azure which we have not used yet. Is it possible to upgrade our existing subscription to include the 180 day period? We'll be very grateful if you could reply ASAP and help us because our app will not function if the services are not ready and the judging process is about to begin. We greatly appreciate any kind of help.

Regards 
Harjoben Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open up a case with Microsoft support.  They should be able to help or at least tell you what is possible:

https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?&c1=501&gprid=14928&&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn